Symfony 7 validation: apply validation group depending on form-input
Following scenario:
I have an entity that is part of a symfony-workflow that represents a rather complex editorial process.
Within my form, certain persons with sufficient permissions are allowed to mark those to leave the state they are currently in with regards to the workflow by checking a check-box.
If that is the case, I want to apply additional validation groups beside the default one.
I have yet to find a way to do this properly. I only found out how to specify validation groups for an entire form-type which is not really what is needed here as the actual validation group is dependent on values that are submitted within the form. So the decision which group(s) should be applied is evaluated after the form was submitted to the server.
Is there a way to do this that doesn't work around or against the framework?
If I inject a ValidatorInterface into my controller I could check against the groups as needed but it would be a real hassle to enrich the form for the response with the violations at the correct paths.

Can you share some code demonstrating what you've tried?

There is a dedicate chapter in the official documentation about this topic: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html

Ohhh! I didnt find that one! I gotta look into it! Thanks!
